# Access to Google Docs owned by former employee

Tags: google-docs

A person left our company, but did not transfer ownership of Google Docs for which they were the owner. Is there any way to gain access to these files without contacting that person directly? These are legal docs that are owned by the company.

Comment: Contact the company's Google Workspace administrator. They can transfer the ownership. See "[Transfer all the files of one user](https://knowledge.workspace.google.com/kb/how-to-transfer-file-ownership-000006588#:~:text=As%20an%20administrator%2C%20you%20can%20transfer%20all%20the%20files%20of%20one)

Comment: Are the documents owned by a consumer account (i.e., an account from the gmail.com domain) or by a managed account / Google Workspace account?